# How to parse a document with html tags?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

Have a document with floating structure:

> some random text
>
> formatting for different source
>
> `<!-- customtag --->`
>
> `<!-- subtag structure --> ... <!-- subtag END -->`

Am looking for something, which I can actually apply at a task of parsing the `custom tag` block and generate an object out of it (multiple per document).

Currently looking in the direction of JAXB, StAX, JSoup and anything google can provide in the matter. JAXB gives a good start, but I cannot see how to configure it's `tag structure`.

Comment: Can you parse the whole doc with JSoup then fetch the custom tag by name?

Comment: Currently investigating JSoup. Problem is, the document isn't html based (no body and other root tags). As a result, it identifies as 1 big node.